# The request failed to run because the batch is aborted, this can be caused by abort signal sent from client

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, task-parallel-library

In my program I use Task Parallel Library to reduce the time of a process.
I use this code to do the work.

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[10]
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoFiles(fullNum,NotFullNum, 1 , (e.Argument as string[])[1])),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoFiles(fullNum,NotFullNum, 2 , (e.Argument as string[])[1])),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoFiles(fullNum,NotFullNum, 3 , (e.Argument as string[])[1])),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoFiles(fullNum,NotFullNum, 4 , (e.Argument as string[])[1])),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoFiles(fullNum,NotFullNum, 5 , (e.Argument as string[])[1])),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoFiles(fullNum,NotFullNum, 6 , (e.Argument as string[])[1])),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoFiles(fullNum,NotFullNum, 7 , (e.Argument as string[])[1])),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoFiles(fullNum,NotFullNum, 8 , (e.Argument as string[])[1])),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoFiles(fullNum,NotFullNum, 9 , (e.Argument as string[])[1])),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoFiles(fullNum,NotFullNum, 10, (e.Argument as string[])[1]))
};

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

The DoFiles() method processes some files and then insert words in the files in database. Every Task process some files. I use this code to insert in database:

```
SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(clsGlobal.cnTashih);
sbc.DestinationTableName = "tblListTekrari_3";
sbc.BulkCopyTimeout = 0;
sbc.WriteToServer(dtT);
sbc.Close();
```

When I run the program sometimes I get this error:

```
Cannot access destination table 'tblListTekrari_3'.

System.Data

The request failed to run because the batch is aborted, this can be caused by abort signal sent from client, or another request is running in the same session, which makes the session busy.

at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerInternal()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServer(Int32 columnCount)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table, DataRowState rowState)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table)
at tashih.frmStart.DoFiles(Int32 countFull, Int32 NotCountFull, Int32 part, String ProjectID)
```

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1):

**Using Parallel Bulk Copy to Copy Data into a Specific Partition**

Use parallel bulk copy to copy data in parallel to a specific partition. Parallel bulk copy substantially increases performance during bcp sessions because it can split large bulk copy jobs into multiple sessions and run the sessions concurrently.

To use parallel bulk copy:

- The destination table must be partitioned.

Use sp_helpartition to see the number of partitions on the table.

Use alter table ... partition to partition the table, if the table is not already partitioned.

- The destination table should not contain indexes because:

If the table has a clustered index, this index determines the physical placement of the data, causing the partition specification in the bcp command to be ignored.

If any indexes exist, bcp automatically uses its slow bulk copy instead of its fast bulk copy mode.

- If nonclustered indexes exist on the tables, parallel bulk copy is
  likely to lead to deadlocks on index pages.
- Each partition should reside on a separate physical disk for the best
  performance.
- Before you copy data into your database, partition the table destined
  to contain the data.
- Parallel bulk copy can copy in to a table from multiple operating
  system files.

For all types of partitioned tables, use:

bcp tablename partition partition_name in file_name

For round-robin partitioned tables only, use:

bcp tablename partition_number in file_name

Comment: Your answer is true when I want to bulk a big data into a table, in this way sqlserver helps save that big data easier to a table. My question is for using multiple bulk copy concurrently :)